# K8s Deployment failed but End points work

Tags: kubernetes, bamboo, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-deployment

I was playing with k8s deployment with change of port for service,container and ingress.I am curious to know how the deployment is working.

my scenario :
To deploy one rest service application hosting 2 endpoints.

Case 1:

containerPort: 8081 - # port for container

port: 8081       #port of the service
targetPort: 8081

Host1 port : 8081  #port of the ingress
Host2 port :8081

Result : deployed successfully using bamboo pipeline as expected.

Case 2: 

*containerPort: 8080 - # port for container*

port: 8080       #port of the service
targetPort: 8081

Host1 port : 8081  #port of the ingress
Host2 port :8081 

Result : Deployment is getting failed in bamboo but health check and all end points are working fine.

Case 3:

containerPort: 8080 - # port for container

port: 8080       #port of the service
targetPort: 808

Host1 port : 8080  #port of the ingress
Host2 port :8080

Result : deployment  unsuccessful in bamboo which is also expected because another host is running also in 8080 in the same cluster.

I am really not sure why Case 2 is failing.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi there, can you please format the question with some `code block` as for now, it's not really easy to read. Also can you provide some more info and background, please ? Remember that we are not working in your current project so we don't know the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

> Case 2:
>
> containerPort: 8080 - # port for container
>
> port: 8080 #port of the service targetPort: 8081
>
> Host1 port : 8081 #port of the ingress Host2 port :8081
>
> Result : Deployment is getting failed in bamboo but health check and
>   all end points are working fine.
>
> I am really not sure why Case 2 is failing. Can someone help me?

You cannot expect it to be working if you set `targetPort` in your `Service` to `8081` and the port that your container exposes (port that your pod is listening on) is `8080`. These two values must much. Please refer to [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) article in official k8s documentation.

Comment: Sorry but why these two values should match?

Comment: If you want to expose some set of `Pods` as a `Service`, apart from setting a `port:` that it will be listening on, you should tell it which ports actual `Pods` are listening on (ports defined in `container:` specification as `containerPort:` ). This is the function of `targetPort:`. You use it so the `Service` knows to which port on the container it should map its `port:` it listens on. If you don't have any `Pods` exposing port `8081` how can you map anything to that port ?